# Can I use ASA5505 to spoof the reply to a heartbeat request?

Tags: cisco-asa, heartbeat, spoofing

I have a CISCO ASA 5505 in a home office. It has two subnet, public and private. There is a wifi belkin router on the private net, which provides wifi for some users. That belkin router sends out heartbeat notice to a pre-programmed ip address, but the packet is dropped by the ASA. I do not want the packet to go through. I prefer the Belkin be unable to phone home like that, but this belkin cannot disable the heartbeat check.

So, I wonder if I can make the ASA reply back to the the belkin hello instead?

Or maybe you can tell me how to make a forwarding setting with the ASA that can re-direct the heartbeat check to a host on the LAN by mapping the phone home IP address to the local network?

Here is the firewall drop message from the belkin in the ASA.

```
3 datetime 50.16.219.4 192.168.3.5 Deny inbound icmp src outside:50.16.219.4 dst inside:192.168.3.5 (type 0, code 0)
```

I'm comfortable with the CISCO ASDM interface, but I managed some config on the command line too.

Another internal DNS server ([like this cure](http://www.zebulak.com/2013/09/belkin-router-heartbeat/)) is not really an option at this point.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What is wrong with leaving the packet dropped as it is now if you don't want it to 'phone home'?  Are services degraded on the router?

Comment: Service is not degraded as far as using the network. But logs accumulate, and the Belkin thinks it is offline. It has a red light, because it cannot phone home, and the wireless windows based clients show a incorrect marker in the internet icon. And, I don't know if the belkin is sending a hello packet that is reaching belkin, leading belkin to keep querying the home office ip. Does not the firewall message mean that the icmp reply is the packet being blocked?

Comment: No, it means that ICMP is being denied to the belkin though.  If it were the reply, you should see ICMPReply being blocked.

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't use the ASA and the router in parallel like that, especially with the Belkin behind the ASA.  I would look at getting a cheap AP the Cisco WAP121, $70 solves your problem and gives you much better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and insights. Do you know if it is possible to make the ASA reply back to the the belkin hello instead? Or, make a forwarding setting with the ASA that can re-direct the heartbeat check to any other host? If it is not possible, then I think the answer to this question is no. But if it is possible, I would be thankful for knowing where to look in the setup docs or ASDM interface for the settings.

Comment: I found a free way. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is yes. It is basically a hairpin NAT, attested to in Cisco page about [dns doctoring](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/115753-dns-doctoring-asa-config.html).

I tried to make this work on another firewall in a different office. Below are some configuration that seems to redirect the traffic as I desired. I made these config in the ASDM, but I am only feeling my way through. I hope an expert can help me find flaws or better ideas.

I put extra comments to explain:

```
Result of the command: "show running-config"
...
!-- this server is monitoring the network anyway, so it is on 24/7
name 192.168.1.66 local-heartbeat.com description attempted destination for spoofed pings
!-- This is the destination that was blocked.
name 50.16.219.4 belkin.heartbeat.com description domain to redirect ping traffic
...
interface Vlan2 nameif outside security-level 0
 ip address 192.168.154.100 255.255.255.0 !-- Front IP of the firewall I working on.
...
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 192.168.250.254   !-- This is the dns in the greater office complex
 domain-name theoraffice.local

!-- I read the next one required to allow interfaces to connect in Hairpin NAT.
!-- I don't know if this is a true hairpin, because the external belkin server
!-- is actually external.
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface

!-- Rule to allow pings to belkin
...
access-list outside_access_in extended permit icmp any host belkin.heartbeat.com 
...
!-- I am behind a firewall at 1.100
icmp permit 192.168.1.100 255.255.255.252 outside
...
nat-control
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
...

!-- This rule is the one that redirects the ping, when I ping with domain name.
static (outside,inside) local-heartbeat.com belkin.heartbeat.com netmask 255.255.255.255 dns 
...
```

That is working when I ping to belkin.com. Example:

```
[auser@192.168.2.20]$ ping heartbeat.belkin.com

Pinging heartbeat.belkin.com [192.168.1.66] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.66: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=63
Reply from 192.168.1.66: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=63
Reply from 192.168.1.66: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=63
Reply from 192.168.1.66: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.66:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 20ms, Average = 13ms
```

In that test, the ping came back from the local server.

Here are config screenshots.

Setting to allow hairpin NAT.
[image: Enable traffic between interfaces]

Allows a ping attempt to the outside heartbeat server.
[image]

Hairpin NAT Rule redirecting the attempt to the local host.
[image: Hairpin NAT rule]

To test it, I removed the only the hairpin NAT rule, then did ipconfig /flushdns on the windows laptop and tried to ping belkin.com.

```
[auser@192.168.2.20]$ ping heartbeat.belkin.com

Pinging heartbeat.belkin.com [50.16.219.4] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 50.16.219.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Now I have two other questions.

First, with the hairpin removed, the ping headed for belkin, and was blocked. This is good, but it surprises me. Why is it blocked, though I made the rule to allow earlier and did not change that access rule at this point?

Second, why did this question get a downgrade?